# Size of Predicate results in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

What is the best way of finding size of a predicate results in hazelcast IMap?

There is no direct size support in MapProxyImpl.java and size() will be calculated on returned collection which in undesired in this case.

Do you have any recommendations ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for an `IMap::size(Predicate)` overload which is not yet available, anyhow it sounds like a nice feature. Would you like to create a feature request for that?

To solve the problem at the moment, I guess the best workaround is using an EntryProcessor, running against all keys, basically executing your predicate and returning 1 or 0 for each key and just sum the result up on the caller. Sorry for not having a better solution but maybe someone else has an amazing idea :)

Comment: Thanks Noctarius !. counter in mapreduce API like in Hadoop also very useful for this usecase.

Comment: Perfect! *thumbs up*

Comment: Map<String, Object> executeOnEntries = map.executeOnEntries(new TestEntryProcessor(), predicate);

class TestEntryProcessor implements EntryProcessor<String, Employee>{
  /**
   * return some value other than null so that entry will be returned in the map.executreOnEntries(processor, Predicate).
   */
  public Object process(Entry<String, Employee> entry) {
   return 1;
  }
  public EntryBackupProcessor<String, Employee> getBackupProcessor() {
   return null;
  }
 }

and executeOnEntries.size() return size. you recommend suggestions to above code?

Answer (score 2):

there is an answer on the ticket

> Since 3.8 you can use map.aggregate(Aggregators.count());

i have not tested it yet