# Total count of Predicate results along with collection with Imap::values(PagingPredicate)

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

IMAP::values(Predicate) returns only Collection for paging predicate as well.

Total count of collection objects very important to use paging predicate.

Is there any way to get the count with paging predicate other than using EntryProcessor to get the size ?

Getting size of predicate using entryprocessor/values(Predicate) is not ideal solution.

Ideally, values(paginated predicate) must return collection + total count. I checked the code operationService.invokeOnTarget(MapService.SERVICE_NAME, operation, member.getAddress()) returning paginated query results. if the items per page is 5, it returns only 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size of Predicate results in Hazelcast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474000/size-of-predicate-results-in-hazelcast)

Comment: No. its not a duplicate. we can get count for paginated predicate using count(predicate) as well. but it's an additional invocation.

Ideally, values(paginated predicate) must return collection + count.

I checked the code operationService.invokeOnTarget(MapService.SERVICE_NAME, operation, member.getAddress()) returning paginated query results. if the items per page is 5, it returns only 5. its good to return total count as well.

Comment: The referenced question answers that as of now, it is not possible to directly  get the number of matches for a predicate, except using an EntryProcessor. It seems to me that PagingPtedicate is just a special case of the previous question.